# Interpolation and forecasting out of 2 values in R

Tags: r, interpolation

I have a vector of yearly population data from 1980 to 2020 with only two values (years 2000 and 2010) and I need to predict the missing data. 
My first thought was to use na.approx to fill in the missing data between 2000 and 2010 and then use the ARIMA model. However, as the population is declining, in the remote future its values would become negative, which is illogical.
My second thought was to use differences of logarithms between the sample data dividing it by 10(since there is a 10 year gap between the actual values) and using it as a percentage change to predict the missing data.
However, I am new to R and statistics so I am not sure if this is the best way to get the predictions. Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about choosing an appropriate statistical method; it is not about programming or R specifically. This question is better suited for a statistics forum like [stats.se]. Once you know what analysis is appropriate for your data but are unsure how to do it in R, then it may make sense to post here.

Comment: "*I have a vector of yearly population data from 1980 to 2020 with only two values (years 2000 and 2010)*" - so what you actually have is two data points, not yearly population data at all. I think you're going to struggle to make sensible predictions with such sparse data. Regardless, this is a stats, not a programming question, and is probably better suited to CrossValidated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the line that the two data points provides does not make intuitive sense, I would recommend just using the average of the two unless you can get additional data. If you are able to get either more yearly data, or even expected variation values, then you can do some additional analysis. But for now, you're kinda stuck.